# Much vs Very usage differences

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference, adverbs

> 1. I was **much** exhausted in the evening. (Here **very** exhausted is wrong)
> 2. She is **very** tired after a day’s work. (Here **much** tired is wrong)

My grammar book said above sentences. Although the kind of sentence construction is same in both sentences why different words (much and very) are used in different places. I am very/ much confused about when to use much and very.

What is the difference between them? When to use very and when to use much?

Comment: I don't know why the book says that. Since _exhausted_ means _very tired_, I don't see that it needs an intensifier at all (though you could say _completely exhausted_.

Comment: The first sentence is incorrect, you could say "very exhausted" and it would still work

Comment: @iggy12345 why is much exhausted incorrect?

Comment: It's not, bit saying that "very exhausted" is incorrect, is.